# High Charts export to PDF

Tags: highcharts

I am using the high charts.And these all have the buttons for export to .PDF on each chart.i want to a another button apart from these buttons.When I click on this button, it export all the high chart in single PDF file. And my whole code in c#

Comment: I have done similar thing for a client, but in php as backend. I used the [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/) library. Its good. Have a try if php is an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can add override button by prepare your own buttons by exporting / buttons parameter

http://jsfiddle.net/fXHB5/8617/

```
 exporting:{
    buttons:[{
        enabled:true,
        align:'right',
        symbol:'triangle',
        onclick:function(){
           alert('aaa');
        }
    }]
},
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons

Comment: Is it possible to customize this button (its design, and DOM place), putting it out of the `div container tag of highcharts` in another section?

Comment: You can render classic html button, catch click action and call chart http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Chart.exportChart